# Is the phrase "a stark contrast" redundant?

Tags: meaning, phrases, redundancy

Merriam-Webster defines stark as *"sharply delineated."*

The same dictionary defines a contrast as a *"juxtaposition of dissimilar elements."*

Doesn't it follow then that *"a stark contrast"* essentially means *"a juxtaposition of very different different elements?"*

If so, would *"a great contrast"* make an acceptable substitute?

Comment: *Stark contrast* is a very common "set term", with [840,000 instances](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stark+contrast%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. There's nothing logically or grammatically odd about a *juxtaposition* involving dissimilar elements. In fact, juxtapositions usually do - if they didn't we wouldn't bother calling attention to them with such a long word. I would advise OP to stick with this as a standard expression - it's several times more common than, for example, *great contrast*.

Comment: Different things may only be _slightly_ different from one another.  You may make a contrast of them, but it would likely not be a stark contrast.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the term is 'set phrase'. 'Set term' might introduce a redundancy where 'set phrase' for a term could do. [Stark contrast is a very common "set term"]

Comment: @Kris: I have no special knowledge of any generally-recognised distinction, if indeed there is one. I note that googling **"set term" linguistics** gets twice as many hits as **"set phrase" linguistics**, but I couldn't see anything obviously differentiating them. To be honest, I just tend to use *"set term"* for simple two-word *adjective+noun* and *adverb+verb* pairings, and *"set phrase"* for any longer expressions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers '*term*' is typically used to refer to a word with  recognized/ specialized meaning, a set phrase, pre-defined expression, etc. in a given domain.

Comment: @Kris: Agreed, but *"term"* there is really just shorthand for *"standard terminology in a specialist area"*, whereas we are talking about *"set terms/phrases/expressions"*, which are *"common [idiomatic] usages familiar to most native speakers"*.

Comment: @Phoenix: If I said anything suggesting *contrast* only applies to *major* differences, I expressed myself badly. What I meant was that *juxtaposition* is more likely to be used where the things being juxtaposed are significantly different - or at least, *in order to call attention to such differences as may exist*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, No, that was addressed to Centigonal.  It follows logically that if there can be a contrast that is most definitely not a stark contrast, then there can be one which most definitely is a stark contrast, hence it cannot be redundant because there is actual additional information contained in the word "stark" that modifies "contrast."

Comment: @Phoenix: Sorry that was just me being careless. Of course you're right to pick up OP on his mistaken preconception re "contrast". And I shouldn't have been so presumptuous as to assume your comment was directed at mine. Consider me duly chastised and chastened! :)

Answer (score 8):

There is no redundancy in 'stark contrast' as in typical cases of redundancy.

*Contrast* is an attribute with degrees of variation: none to total.

*stark* in *stark contrast* merely qualifies the attribute to the level of extreme perceptibility.

Two things may be different to some extent. The difference is not perceptible so long as the contrast is below a certain threshold. Beyond that, and then a little further, the difference becomes so "glaring" that it comes out prominently: 'stark contrast'.

Answer (score 2):

You could argue that *stark contrast* is redundant.  However, it is perfectly acceptable to use redundancy or repetition for emphasis.  This is exactly what is being done in this somewhat ideomatic expression.  If *stark contrast* is leaning too far towards cliché for you then you could substitute another intensifier for *stark*, but then you lose the benefit of clarity that comes with a well established expression.

Comment: Such idioms, set phrases and 'established expressions' are generally not without a good semantic basis. Among them, *stark contrast* is grammatical, is correctly understood sans hyperbole, as is also technically accurate. So, there is no redundancy as such.

Answer (score 1):

I echo Kris' comment and add as a for-instance that for a long time TVs had contrast dials that were analogue. You could twiddle that knob all the way from no contrast (black screen) through to stark. Yes, my TV had a label with STARK written on it.

So no, it's not redundant.

Comment: Actually it didn't have that label, but I thought it should.